# I want to check band skipping in antenna machines tested data by compare two csv files using Python, one is tested file and the other one is reference

Tags: python

[Comparative view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YScM0.png)

firstly program open 1st csv reference file and read all antenna bands data then open other tested phone file and compare antenna bands whether any band skipped or not in tested phone data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this.  The following code returns records where column 3 is different between the 2 data sets (COL_3_x is column 3 from the LH table and COL_3_y is column 3 in the right hand table).

```
import pandas as pd

#load LH table
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({
'PHONE_TEST_TYPE': ['WCDMA_B1_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B2_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B3_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B5_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B8_CouplingTest']
,'COL_2': ['','' , '', '20', '20']
,'COL_3': ['skipped', 'skipped', 'skipped', 22.9621, 23.0011]
,'COL_4': ['','' , '',26, 26]
,'COL_5': ['','' , '', '406ms', '453ms']
})

#load RH table
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({
'PHONE_TEST_TYPE': ['WCDMA_B1_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B2_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B3_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B5_CouplingTest', 'WCDMA_B8_CouplingTest']
,'COL_2': ['','' , '', '20', '20']
,'COL_3': ['skipped', 'skipped', 'skipped', 'skipped' ,'skipped']
,'COL_4': ['','' , '',26, 26]
,'COL_5': ['','' , '', '406ms', '453ms']
})

#Combine via left join
DF3 = DF1.merge(DF2, on='PHONE_TEST_TYPE', how='left')

# Create a filter to identify records missing in column 3 on RH table.
FILT = DF3['COL_3_x'] != DF3['COL_3_y']

# present result in dataframe
DF3[FILT]
```

result:
[image]